# if $f(g(x))$ is 1 to 1, then is g 1 to 1?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Im working on practice problems that the instructor gave us yesterday and Im stuck with this question..

the question is: if $f\circ g $ is one to one, then is $g$ one to one?

Im not sure how to solve this problem.. Detailed explanation will be very much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $f\circ g$ is one-one, this means g is one-one, because if $g(x_1)=g(x_2)\implies f(g(x_1))=f(g(x_2))$ which makes $f\circ g$ many-one.

Comment: thank you! what does many-one means? i need to wait 6 minutes to accept your answer..

Comment: many-one is opposite of one-one(1-1) @johnivan

Comment: @johnivan maybe more detail might be useful; anyways it depends on your examining body, maybe ask your teacher?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $x\neq y$. Then, $f(g(x))\neq f(g(y))$ preventing the possibility that $g(x)=g(y)$. So $g$ must also be one-to-one.